# Spark SQL - count number of distinct word in all columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is a DataFrame df_titles with one column "title":

```
+--------------------+
|               title|
+--------------------+
|      harry_potter_1|
|      harry_potter_2|
+--------------------+
```

I want to know the number of unique terms appearing in the titles, where the terms are delimited by "_", and get something like this:

```
+--------------------+------+
|                term| count|
+--------------------+------+
|               harry|     2|   
|              potter|     2| 
|                   1|     1| 
|                   2|     1| 
+--------------------+------+
```

I am thinking of creating a new_df with columns "term" and "count", and for each row in df_titles, split the string and insert [string, 1] to the new_df. Then maybe reduce the new df by "term":

```
  val test = Seq.empty[Term].toDF()
  df.foreach(spark.sql("INSERT INTO test VALUES (...)"))
  ...
```

But I am stuck with the code. How should I proceed? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spark built-in functions such as [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [`explode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to transform your dataframe of titles to dataframe of terms and then do a simple [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupBy(col1:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset). Your code should be:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, desc, explode, split}

df_titles
  .select(explode(split(col("title"), "_")).as("term"))
  .groupBy("term")
  .count()
  .orderBy(desc("count")) // optional, to have count in descending order
```

Usually, when you have to perform something over a dataframe, it is better to first try to use a combination of spark built-in functions that you can find in [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html)

#### Details

Starting from `df_titles`:

```
+--------------+
|title         |
+--------------+
|harry_potter_1|
|harry_potter_2|
+--------------+
```

`split` creates an array of words separated by `_`:

```
+-------------------+
|split(title, _, -1)|
+-------------------+
|[harry, potter, 1] |
|[harry, potter, 2] |
+-------------------+
```

Then, `explode` creates one line per item in array created by `split`:

```
+------+
|col   |
+------+
|harry |
|potter|
|1     |
|harry |
|potter|
|2     |
+------+
```

`.as("term")` renames column `col` to `term`:

```
+------+
|term  |
+------+
|harry |
|potter|
|1     |
|harry |
|potter|
|2     |
+------+
```

Then `.groupBy("term")` with `.count()` aggregates counting by `term`, `count()` is a shortcut for `.agg(count("term").as("count"))`

```
+------+-----+
|term  |count|
+------+-----+
|harry |2    |
|1     |1    |
|potter|2    |
|2     |1    |
+------+-----+
```

And finally `.orderBy(desc("count"))` orders count in reverse order:

```
+------+-----+
|term  |count|
+------+-----+
|harry |2    |
|potter|2    |
|1     |1    |
|2     |1    |
+------+-----+
```